# Drawing rectangles around vertical groups of pixels having the same value

Tags: matlab, plot, grouping, visualization, matlab-figure

Consider the following visualization of a 7x5 matrix consisting of 3 distinct regions/values:

```
bL = toeplitz( [zeros(1,5) -2*ones(1,2)], [0 -ones(1,4)] ); 
hF = figure(); hA = axes(hF);    
imagesc(hA,bL); axis(hA,'image'); set(hA,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]);
N = 4; cmap = parula(N); colormap(cmap(1:end-1,:));
```

[image: Unselected]

Now let's say I "select" 0 or more pixels in each column such that:

- Selected pixels can only be chosen in the green region.
- Selected pixels are always contiguous.
- Selection is performed by assigning a constant new value, which is different from the 3 initial regions.

Several examples of selection (using the value `1`):

```
%Example 1:
cSF = toeplitz([ones(1,1) zeros(1,4) -2*ones(1,2)],[1 -ones(1,4)]);
%Example 2:
oSF = toeplitz( [zeros(1,5) -2*ones(1,2)], [0 -ones(1,4)] );
oSF(end-2:end,find(any(oSF==-2,1),1,'last')+1:end) = 1; 
%Example 3:
iSF = toeplitz([ones(1,3) zeros(1,2) -2*ones(1,2)],[1 -ones(1,4)]);
% Plot:
hF = figure();
hP(1) = subplot(1,3,1); imagesc(cSF);
hP(2) = subplot(1,3,2); imagesc(oSF);
hP(3) = subplot(1,3,3); imagesc(iSF);
axis(hP,'image'); set(hP,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]);
```

[image: Possible selections]

My objective is to draw a set of rectangles encompassing "selected" (yellow) pixels belonging to the same column. For the examples above, the results should look like this (respectively):

[image: Desired result]

The way I see it, for the code to be general it should accept: (1) an axes handle where the `imagesc` should be plotted; (2) a `data` array; (3) a value found in the `data` array, representing "chosen" pixels; and optionally the color of the enclosed pixels.

I found some ways of doing this using `patch` and `rectangle` (see [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965921/3372061)), but I'm wondering if this can be achieved with fewer function calls or in other ways I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Loopless solution using [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html):

Here's a solution that generates coordinates for `patch` without needing a loop:

```
function column_highlight(hA, data, selectionVal)

  assert(nargin >= 2);
  if (nargin < 3) || isempty(selectionVal)
    selectionVal = 1;
  end

  nCol = size(data, 2);
  data = diff([false(1, nCol); (data == selectionVal); false(1, nCol)]);
  [r, c] = find(data);
  r = reshape(r-0.5, 2, []);
  c = c(1:2:end);
  X = [c-0.5 c+0.5 c+0.5 c-0.5].';
  Y = r([1 1 2 2], :);
  patch(hA, 'XData', X, 'YData', Y, 'FaceColor', 'none');

end
```

### Solution using [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html):

If you have the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html), you can solve this by labeling each masked column section and getting the `'BoundingBox'` shape measure using `regionprops`:

```
function column_highlight(hA, data, selectionVal)

  assert(nargin >= 2);
  if (nargin < 3) || isempty(selectionVal)
    selectionVal = 1;
  end

  labelMat = bsxfun(@times, (data == selectionVal), 1:size(data, 2));
  coords = regionprops(labelMat, 'BoundingBox');
  coords = vertcat(coords.BoundingBox);
  coords(:, 3:4) = coords(:, 1:2)+coords(:, 3:4);
  X = coords(:, [1 3 3 1]).';
  Y = coords(:, [4 4 2 2]).';
  patch(hA, 'XData', X, 'YData', Y, 'FaceColor', 'none');

end
```

Answer (score 3):

#### A solution using [`rectangle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html):

```
function markStreaksRect(hA, data, selectionVal)
% Check inputs:
assert(nargin >= 2); if nargin < 3 || isempty(selectionVal), selectionVal = 1; end
% Create a mask for "selected" values:
oneMask = data == selectionVal;
% Find the first encountered "selected" element from both the top and the bottom:
[~,I1] = max(oneMask,[],1); [~,I2] = max(flipud(oneMask),[],1);
% Express the "selected" extent as a 2 row vector:
firstLast = [I1; size(oneMask,1)-I2+1].*any(oneMask,1);
% For nonzero extents, plot shifted rectangles:
for ind1 = find(all(firstLast,1))  
  rectangle(hA,'Position',[ind1-0.5, firstLast(1,ind1)-0.5, 1, diff(firstLast(:,ind1))+1 ]);
end
```

#### A solution using [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html):

```
function markStreaksPatch(hA, data, selectionVal)
% Check inputs:
assert(nargin >= 2); if nargin < 3 || isempty(selectionVal), selectionVal = 1; end
% Create a mask for "selected" values:
oneMask = data == selectionVal;
% Find the first encountered "selected" element from both the top and the bottom:
[~,I1] = max(oneMask,[],1); [~,I2] = max(flipud(oneMask),[],1);
% Express the "selected" extent as a 2 row vector:
firstLast = [I1; size(oneMask,1)-I2+1].*any(oneMask,1);
% For nonzero extents, plot shifted patches:
for ind1 = find(all(firstLast,1))  
  [XX,YY] = meshgrid(ind1-0.5 + [0 1], firstLast(1,ind1)-0.5+[0 diff(firstLast(:,ind1))+1]);
  patch(hA, XX(:), [YY(1:2) YY(4:-1:3)], 'y', 'FaceAlpha', 0);
end
```

The above solutions can be tested using:

```
function q45965920
iSF = toeplitz([ones(1,3) zeros(1,2) -2*ones(1,2)],[1 -ones(1,4)]);
hF = figure(); hA = axes(hF); imagesc(hA,iSF); 
axis(hA,'image'); set(hA,'XTick',[],'YTick',[]);
```

...then running either `markStreaksRect(hA, iSF, 1);` or `markStreaksPatch(hA, iSF, 1);` produces the desired result.